# Turn MongoDB Secondary into a standalone instance

Tags: mongodb

I have an instance of mongo that was previously in a replica set. The other nodes in the replica set (including the primary) have died and I won't be able to get them back.

I can connect to the remaining node and read but not write.
`not master, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'not master', 'code': 10107, 'codeName': 'NotMaster'}`

How can I reconfigure this instance to be standalone for now without losing and of the data on it? I might then add more nodes at a later date?

Comment: How do you connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by leaving the instance in a replica set, but removing the other instances.

From the mongo console I did:

```
cfg = rs.conf()
printjson(cfg)
```

Which showed me a list of the members of the replica set. I then modified the config to only contain one member:

```
cfg.members = [cfg.members[2]]   // Member 2 is the only one up
rs.reconfig(cfg, {force : true}) // Reconfigure with the new config
```

I can now connect to the single instance with the same config that I used to use for the larger replica set.